# Ao usar tag div dentro de um elemento pai que possui padding, aṕenas o padding esquerdo é mostrado

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Ao usar `<div>` dentro de um elemento `<figcaption>` com `padding: 10px` e colocando o div com `bottom: 0px` relativo ao `<figcaption>`, o padding direito do `<figcaption>` não aparece.. Alguém pode me explicar porque isso acontece?

```css
figure.foto-legenda {
  border: 8px solid #80C46A;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
  position: relative;
  width: 364px;
  height: 232px;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(192, 245, 175, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

p {
  text-indent: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.foto-legenda-texto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="_imagens/mapa-meca-ate-medina.jpeg" alt="Mapa da Arábia Saudita, mostrando as cidades de Meca e Medina" />
  <figcaption>
    <div class="foto-legenda-texto">
      <h4>Hégira: Fuga de Meca para Medina em 586.</h4>
      <p>Em 1º de setembro de 622 d.C, Maomé foge para Iatrebe em Medina.</p>
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, "figure.foto-legenda figcaption" sem a propriedade padding:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que o [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) faz com que você posicione o elemento conforme as especificações das propriedades `top`, `right`, `bottom` e `left`, então acaba "desconsiderando" esse `padding` do pai.

Para ter o efeito desejado, você pode usar o valor [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) para que o elemento tenha o mesmo `padding` que o pai.

```css
div.foto-legenda-texto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Para alinhar a base */
    left: 0; /* Para alinhar à esquerda */
    padding: inherit; /* Para ter o mesmo padding que o pai */
}
```

Veja funcionando:

```css
figure.foto-legenda {
  border: 8px solid #80C46A;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
  position: relative;
  width: 364px;
  height: 232px;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
  background-color: rgba(192, 245, 175, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

p {
  text-indent: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.foto-legenda-texto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* Para alinhar a base */
  left: 0; /* Para alinhar à esquerda */
  padding: inherit; /* Para ter o mesmo padding que o pai */
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/364/232" alt="Mapa da Arábia Saudita, mostrando as cidades de Meca e Medina" />
  <figcaption>
    <div class="foto-legenda-texto">
      <h4>Hégira: Fuga de Meca para Medina em 586.</h4>
      <p>Em 1º de setembro de 622 d.C, Maomé foge para Iatrebe em Medina.</p>
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```